# Mandrill Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 435 4.7.8 Error: authentication failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mandrill

Have an issue with delivering mails via Mandrill at production, at localhost everything is fine.

My config:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :port =>           '587',
      :address =>        'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
      :user_name =>      'my_mail@gmail.com',
      :password =>       'password',
      :authentication => 'plain',
      :domain => 'http://example.net/',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Error log:

Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 435 4.7.8 Error: authentication failed:

```
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:976:in `check_auth_response'
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:740:in `auth_plain'
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:732:in `authenticate'
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:567:in `do_start'
    from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
    from /home/deployer/apps/shinaswiss/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
    from /home/deployer/apps/shinaswiss/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:2141:in `do_delivery'
    from /home/deployer/apps/shinaswiss/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `block in deliver'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with my password.
At production I changed my plain password to API KEY and it helped to solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

:domain is specified incorrectly. It should be 'example.com', not 'http://example.com/'.

Comment: Mandrill accepted such specification.
Maybe something changed with api at last time?